# Capturing video at 60 FPS with the front camera on iPad Pro 9.7"

Tags: ios, avfoundation, frame-rate, avcapturesession

I am trying to configure the `AVCaptureSession` to grab frames at 640x480 at 60 FPS with the front camera on iPad Pro 9.7".

During the configuration I have these lines:

```
  for videoFormat in (captureDevice?.formats)! {

    let descriptions = videoFormat.formatDescription
    let dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(descriptions)
    let width = dimensions.width
    let height = dimensions.height

    if ((width != 640) || (height != 480)) {
      continue
    }
    //      let videoFormatDescriptionRef = videoFormat.formatDescription

    for range in videoFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges {
      if range.maxFrameRate == 60 {
        bestFormat = videoFormat
        bestFrameRateRange = range
        break
      }
    }

    if ( bestFormat != nil) {
      captureDevice!.activeFormat = bestFormat!;
      captureDevice!.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange!.minFrameDuration;
      captureDevice!.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange!.minFrameDuration;
      break
    }
  }
```

When I list the video formats supported by the camera I get this list:

```
<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa1fc0 'vide'/'420v'  192x 144, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:54.400, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @6.67), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa1fb0 'vide'/'420f'  192x 144, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:54.400, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @6.67), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR, supports wide color> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa1fa0 'vide'/'420v'  352x 288, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:49.895, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @3.33), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa1f90 'vide'/'420f'  352x 288, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:49.895, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @3.33), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR, supports wide color> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa1f80 'vide'/'420v'  480x 360, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:54.400, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @2.67), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa1f70 'vide'/'420f'  480x 360, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:54.400, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @2.67), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR, supports wide color> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa1f60 'vide'/'420v'  640x 480, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:54.400, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @2.00), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa1f50 'vide'/'420f'  640x 480, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:54.400, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @2.00), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR, supports wide color> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa2030 'vide'/'420v'  960x 540, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:58.480, max zoom:48.50 (upscales @1.43), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa2040 'vide'/'420f'  960x 540, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:58.480, max zoom:48.50 (upscales @1.43), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR, supports wide color> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa2050 'vide'/'420v' 1024x 768, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:54.400, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @1.25), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa2060 'vide'/'420f' 1024x 768, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:54.400, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @1.25), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR, supports wide color> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa2070 'vide'/'420v' 1280x 720, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:58.480, max zoom:48.50 (upscales @1.08), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa2080 'vide'/'420f' 1280x 720, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:58.480, max zoom:48.50 (upscales @1.08), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR, supports wide color> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa2090 'vide'/'420v' 1280x 960, { 2- 60 fps}, HRSI:2576x1932, fov:54.400, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @1.00), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa20a0 'vide'/'420f' 1280x 960, { 2- 60 fps}, HRSI:2576x1932, fov:54.400, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @1.00), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports wide color>
```

Because I am particularly interested in 640x480, I will want one of these:

```
<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa1f60 'vide'/'420v'  640x 480, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:54.400, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @2.00), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR> 

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa1f50 'vide'/'420f'  640x 480, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:54.400, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @2.00), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR, supports wide color>
```

I choose the first one:

```
<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282fa1f60 'vide'/'420v'  640x 480, { 2- 60 fps}, fov:54.400, max zoom:60.00 (upscales @2.00), ISO:34.0-2176.0, SS:0.000013-0.500000, supports HDR>
```

If I understood this correctly, if I choose this format I can set any frame rate I want between 2 and 60 FPS.

I choose 60 FPS, by setting these lines:

```
  captureDevice!.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange!.minFrameDuration;
  captureDevice!.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange!.minFrameDuration;
```

I have even tried this

```
let fps60 = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 60)
captureDevice!.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = fps60;
captureDevice!.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = fps60;
```

Whatever I do, video is always captured at 30 FPS.

I am setting the capture session with

```
self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.vga640x480
let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .front)
```

Note: I am not particularly interested by 640x480. It only seemed to be the lightest resolution I could think that would make capture faster. I would go for any resolution that gives me 60 FPS on the front camera.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days I found the problem.

You cannot use this line

```
self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.vga640x480
```

after configuring the session or it will undo everything you do to some internal standard.

This line has to be one of the first things you do.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be incorrect, because `bestFrameRateRange!.minFrameDuration` would have been 2?

```
captureDevice!.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange!.minFrameDuration;
captureDevice!.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange!.minFrameDuration;
```

Also, are you calling `lockForConfiguration` before you set the frame duration?

```
do {
    try captureDevice!.lockForConfiguration()
    let fps60 = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 60)
    captureDevice!.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = fps60;
    captureDevice!.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = fps60;
    captureDevice!.unlockForConfiguration()
} catch {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: both are equal to minFrameDuration because minFrameDuration = 1/60, forcing the system to 60 FPS. The configuration performs without error but the camera continues to grab at 30 FPS. Yes, I am using lockForConfiguration.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I thought it was framerate.

I don't have a iPad pro, but when I tested Apple's sample code [RosyWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110) on iPhone 6, it seems to work fine. I can capture video with front camera at 60fps by changing framerate to 60 and preset to `AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480` (the sample code is using Objective C). Would you mind testing the sample code on your device?

Comment: No problem. I am testing it on the device. It is very strange because the device tell me that it has 60 FPS but when I set it continues to shot it at 30 FPS. Bug? who knows. Thanks.

Comment: I meant testing RosyWriter on your device. Because when I tested it on iPad mini (2nd generation), it does report 30 rather than 60, `<AVFrameRateRange: 0x101d66f40 2 - 30>`. And if you set it to 60, there will be an exception `Unsupported frame duration - use -activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges to discover valid ranges'`

Comment: 60 FPS is a valid framerate for the the format I am using, like exposed in the question.

Comment: I know, which is why I thought it might be a good idea to test RosyWriter on your device.
If RosyWriter works fine, that means the problem is in your code
If it does not, then the problem could be either iOS version or device.